# Error receiving server response

Tags: android, python

I wrote a server-client communication between PC and mobile phone. The PC is the server written in Python and the handy is the client written in Android (Java).

After the registration, both sides send their names and some JSON-String is sending from mobile phone to the PC. *This works without any exception*.

However, when I try to receive the server answer after checking the incoming data, I get the following exception:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@30ad25c
time:69321819
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
W/System.err: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)
W/System.err: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.getInputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
W/System.err: at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:363)
W/System.err: at com.dmd_data.soft_zeiterfassung.daten_transfer$MyClientTask.doInBackground(daten_transfer.java:267)
W/System.err:     at com.dmd_data.soft_zeiterfassung.daten_transfer$MyClientTask.doInBackground(daten_transfer.java:108)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.dmd_data.soft_zeiterfassung time:69322601
D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@30ad25c time:69323717
```

My Android code looks like this:

```
    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String message = "";
    String response = "";
    String failMessage = "";
    int timeoutMs;
    String kontoVorname;
    String kontoNachname;
    String userName;

    MyClientTask(String addr){

        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = 9090;
        timeoutMs = 1000;
        SharedPreferences systemDATA = getSharedPreferences("konto",0);
        kontoVorname = systemDATA.getString("editText_vorname", "");
        kontoNachname = systemDATA.getString("editText_nachname", "");
        userName = kontoVorname+" "+kontoNachname;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        JSONArray arb_List = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray mat_List = new JSONArray();

        Cursor arb_Cursor = My_Database.getAllData();

        if (arb_Cursor.getCount() == 0){

            Intent click_datenbank = new Intent(daten_transfer.this,pop_datenbank.class);
            startActivity(click_datenbank);

        }else {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {

                SocketAddress sock_addresse = new InetSocketAddress(dstAddress, dstPort);
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(sock_addresse, timeoutMs);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                failMessage = "IP-ADRESSE UNBEKANNT:\n" + e.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                failMessage = "PC NICHT ERREICHBAR:\n"+ e.toString();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
            String dateTime = sdf.format(new Date());

            //Receive server name
            ByteArrayOutputStream bAPS_Name = new ByteArrayOutputStream(25000);
            byte[] bytes_Name = new byte[25000];
            int int_server;
            InputStream input_Name = null;
            try {
                input_Name = socket.getInputStream();
                int_server = input_Name.read(bytes_Name);
                bAPS_Name.write(bytes_Name, 0, int_server);
                response += bAPS_Name.toString("UTF-8");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Create datalist
            arb_Cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (arb_Cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                int totalArbeit = arb_Cursor.getColumnCount();
                JSONObject row_SEND = new JSONObject();

                for( int i=0 ;  i< totalArbeit ; i++ ){

                    if( arb_Cursor.getColumnName(i) != null ){

                        try{
                            if( arb_Cursor.getString(i) != null ){

                                row_SEND.put(arb_Cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  arb_Cursor.getString(i) );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row_SEND.put( "NONE" , "---" );
                            }
                        }
                        catch( Exception e )
                        {
                            e.getMessage();
                            failMessage = "SORRY,SOMETHING GOES WRONG:\n" + e.toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                arb_List.put(row_SEND);
                arb_Cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            arb_Cursor.close();

            //Send
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){

                json.put("User",userName);
                json.put("Datetime",dateTime);
                json.put("Datalist",arb_List);
                writer.write(json.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                failMessage = "SORRY, SOMETHING GOES WRONG...:\n" + e.toString();
            }

            // Until here it works
            //##################################################################################

            InputStream input_Response = null;
            try {
                input_Response = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(input_Response));
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    message += line;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //##################################################################################
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (failMessage.length()!= 0){
            Toast.makeText(daten_transfer.this,failMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Intent click_transfer = new Intent(daten_transfer.this,pop_wlan.class);
            //startActivity(click_transfer);
        }
        else{
            SharedPreferences systemDATA = getSharedPreferences("konto",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = systemDATA.edit();
            //editor.putString("failmessage",failMessage);
            //editor.commit();
            editor.putString("response",response);
            editor.commit();

            if (response.length() != 0){
                Intent click_transfer = new Intent(daten_transfer.this,pop_tansfer.class);
                startActivity(click_transfer);
            }

            textView_show.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything as far as I could, but no matter what I do, I always get the answer:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the OutputStreamWriter writer variable after you are done with the out streaming. The socket is busy as you are still using it. 
Try the following snippet

```
json.put("User",userName);
json.put("Datetime",dateTime);
json.put("Datalist",arb_List);
writer.write(json.toString());
writer.close();
```

It's a good practice to close the socket too after the usage.